# Quotient of a polynomial ring with a prime ideal is Cohen$-$Macaulay

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay-rings

> **[Bruns-Herzog, Exercise 2.1.17]** Let $k$ be a field and $R = k[x_1, . . . , x_n]$. Suppose $\mathfrak{p} \subset R$ is a prime ideal, $ht\mathfrak{p} \in \{0, 1, n − 1, n\}$. Show that $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is Cohen$-$Macaulay.

Dimension of $R$ is $n$. If $ht\mathfrak{p}=0$ or $n$, we are done. So suppose $ht\mathfrak{p}$ is non-trivial. From here I can't proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  I think there must be some mistake.  There are height $2$ primes $\mathfrak{p}$ in $R=k[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ such that the quotient $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is not Cohen-Macaulay.  This is related to "Hartshorne's connectedness theorem": there exist height $2$ primes such that $\text{Spec}(R/\mathfrak{p})$ fails to be locally connected after removing a codimension $2$ subset.

Comment: @JasonStarr Yes, but $2$ is not in $\{0,1,3,4\}$. I believe the exercise is correct as stated.

Comment: @DaveBenson.  I read too quickly: I thought the list was $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$.  Yes, of course the exercise is then correct: Cartier divisors are Cohen-Macaulay, zero-dimensional Noetherian rings are Cohen-Macaulay, and one-dimensional, reduced Noetherian rings are Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: I think this question is much more suited to MathStackExchange than MathOverflow. But, to answer your question, for the case that $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{p}) = 1$, use that $R$ is a UFD so height one primes are principal, meaning $\mathfrak{p}=(x)$ for some non-zerodivisor $x \in R$. For the case that $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{p})=n-1$, as @JasonStarr says, since $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime, $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is a one-dimensional domain (hence reduced), and thus any nonzero element is a non-zerodivisor so $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: @walkar yes I was in a doubt whether I should post it in MSE or I should post it in MOF, but thank you, I have understood the solution.